# How to create a dotted grid in react using material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a dotted grid using a grid system from the `material-ui`. The Grid should look somewhat like the image that is given below.

[image]

I think that it might help for a responsive design if the dotted grid is built out of a grid system using the `materail-ui` library.

Thank You!!!

Comment: What kind of functionality does the grid need to have? Would a repeating background image be a plausible solution?

Comment: Yes!! that might work!!